# /etc/init.d/<program> or /etc/rc.d/init.d/<program>?

Tags: linux

I check the status of the vncserver program and found it to be available in both:

/etc/init.d/vncserver
and
/etc/rc.d/init.d/vncserver

Both works, but which one is the "real" one?

Comment: This is not a programming related question and should be closed/moved.

Comment: Why do people vote to move everything vaguely related to Linux to ServerFault? This is clearly a question for SuperUser.

Comment: This depends on your RC and Linux distribution.

Answer (score 7):

The "real" one is `/etc/init.d/<<script>>` since rc.d is for the system startup.

You can also use `service vncserver start`

Edit: in some linux distribs, rc.d doesn't exist as it in /etc

```
$ ls /etc/rc
rc0.d/    rc1.d/    rc2.d/    rc3.d/    rc4.d/    rc5.d/    rc6.d/    rc.local  rcS.d/
```

Comment: Interesting, but looks like I don't have the service program on the linux machine :-(


$service vncserver status
bash: service: command not found

Comment: It's usually in /sbin, which will be in your path if you log in as root. If you just su / sudo you'll need to do `/sbin/service vncserver`. Or your distro might not provide one - it's definitely there in RHEL/Fedora/CentOS

Comment: Yep, /sbin/service indeed!  Thx

Answer (score 6):

In Red Hat based distributions, `/etc/init.d` is a symbolic link to `/etc/rc.d/init.d`, so both listings actually refer to the same exact file.

Comment: You are right!
ls -l /etc/init.d
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 11 Aug 22  2007 /etc/init.d -> rc.d/init.d

Comment: @deesto Thanks - you're right, most of my experience is with Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS, but I had thought that was common beyond Red Hat. I realise Ubuntu is widely used nowadays and they like to do everything different though!

Answer (score 0):

Realone is a `/etc/rc.d/init.d/vncserver`